# can't edit a bundle product after adding to cart

Tags: magento-1.9

everything is working fine, the product is added to the cart with the correct default options with default quantities. But when I press edit from the shopping cart page I see all the options has the default quantity value. when I changed options qty and press add to cart button getting scripting error like following.

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'customQty' of undefined
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'reloadPrice' of undefined
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'changeOptionQty' of undefined.

Please help me to fix this issue.